# Electron is not working and giving an error that i cant find anything on

Tags: node.js, electron

Electron will not start. In the console it tells me

```
[6520:0618/131330.291:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(332)] Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
[6520:0618/131330.291:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(332)] Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
[6520:0618/131330.292:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(332)] Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
[6520:0618/131330.292:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(332)] Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details.
```

**I've reinstalled electron many times but it did not resolve the issue.**

Nothing has worked and I've no clue how to fix it

Here's my code

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "thungy",
    "private": true,
    "main": "electron.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron": "^25.1.1"
    }
}
```

`electron.js`

```
const { screen, app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

app.on("ready", () => {
    const { height, width } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        titleBarStyle: "hidden",
        height: height,
        width: width,
        center: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });

    window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/index.html"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, newton. but still having the issue.  do you know of anything that may help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and then reinstalling. PS: You can drop the leading backslash in `/public/index.html` as [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) will automatically add the directory seperator between path segments.

Comment: Facing the similar issue but with a different kind of message, ERROR:node_bindings.cc(145)] Fatal error in V8: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.

Comment: @midnight-coding yes mu;ltiple multiple times. I eventually solved this issue. but do not remember how. It was fairly simple